# Laravel relationship with a link table - Confused

Tags: php, laravel

I'm playing with laravel for the first time and i'm a little confused on how to achieve a link table relationship. I have 3 tables: **Tank,** **TankContent** and **Content**

I have the following models:

Tank:

```
   class Tank extends Model
    {
        public function getTankContent()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\TankContent', 'tankID', 'tankID');   
        }
    }
```

TankContent:

```
class TankContent extends Model
{  
    public function getTank()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tank', 'tankID', 'tankID');    
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Content', 'contentID', 'contentID');   
    }
}
```

Content:

```
class Content extends Model
{    
    public function getContentTanks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContentTank', 'contentID', 'contentID'); 
    }
}
```

Now im trying to call say tankID 2 and get all the content details inside of that

```
$content = Tank::find(2);
$items = $content->getTankContent;
```

This will list me the content. But then how do i go about linking the results to **getContent()** from the TankContent model?

Thanks in advance. Hopefully I just need it explaining and then it will all click.

p.s i have tried reading the https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many and im still stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TankContent isn't required,  the belongsToMany relationship methods belong on the Tank and Content models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

From here you can see there is no RoleUser model, the models are only Role and User.  The belongsToMany relationship on those models defines that the intermediate, or pivot, table is role_user.

You can additionally define other fields on that relationship with withPivot() chained onto the belongsToMany method. (read "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns"). Therefore, there is likely no reason to have a separate model for the intermediate/pivot table.

Comment: I should prehaps of specified that TankContent has other fields on it like DateAdded. So its a link table but there could be 4 items of one type of content in a tank each needing a date stamp

Comment: @JustinDonnnelly, did you read the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: Sorry this is just annoying me! I'll try it now :)

Comment: Thanks, im all sorted now. Think I just needed someone to tell me i was being stupid!